# How to make the pagination a component in Sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, sails.js, ejs

I use sailsjs and ejs template engine to build my website. And I use bootstrap. I have found that the pager appears in almost of my pages. So I want to make it a component, which can be inserted into other ejs pages without pain. Because each pager has different jump urls but with the same `page` query, `include` keyword might not help from ejs.

How can I do it?

Comment: POST SOME CODE please!

Comment: You mean you have some pagination widget created that is repeated in every controller + view? And you want to include that in your views?. Like Bwaxxlo said, add some code, and try to explain better, i'm not sure i'm catching.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a pattern like this

a template.ejs

```
 <% if (typeof paginateurl != 'undefined' && typeof count != 'undefined') { %>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
    <ul class="pagination col-md-8 col-xs-12 tcenter">
        <% for (i = 1; i < totalpages; i++) { %>
        <li <% if (i == currentpage)  { %> class="active" <% } %>>
            <a href="<%- paginateurl %><%- i %>"><%- i %></a></li>
        <% } %>    
    </ul> 
</div>
<% }%>
```

and by adding this in your listing template

```
<% include pagination %>
```

Answer (score 0):

More complex example with next/prev button:
There is still some logic in this template, couse i have no time to refactor it. It is there to make it look more like this:
Prev 1 ... 3 4 *5* 6 7 ... 10 Next

```
<% if(pages > 1) { %>
    <div class="prev">
        <% if(page > 1) { %>
            <a href="<%= link + linkDelimiter + (page-1) %>">Prev</a>
        <% } %>
    </div>

    <div class="numbers">
        <% if(page == 1) { %>
            <span class='current'>1</span>
        <% } else {%>
            <a class='page' href="<%= link + linkDelimiter + 1 %>">1</a>
        <% } %>

        <% if((page - 2) > 1) { %>
            ...
        <% } %>

        <% var start = page - 1 %>
        <% var end = page + 1 %>

        <% var addToStart = end - pages %>

        <% if (addToStart < 0) { %>
            <% addToStart = 0 %>
        <% }; %>

        <% var addToEnd = 3 - end %>
        <% if (addToEnd < 0) { %>
            <% addToEnd = 0 %>
        <% }; %>

        <% for(var i=(start - addToStart); i <= (end + addToEnd); i++) {%>
            <% if(i > 1 && i < pages) { %>
                <% if(page == i) { %>
                    <span class='current'><%= i %></span>
                <% } else { %>
                    <a class='page' href="<%= link + linkDelimiter + i %>"><%= i %></a>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        <% }%>

        <% if((page + 2) < pages) { %>
            ...
        <% } %>

        <% if(page == pages) { %>
            <span class='current'><%= pages %></span>
        <% } else { %>
            <a class='page' href="<%= link + linkDelimiter + pages %>"><%= pages %></a>
        <% } %>
    </div>

    <div class="next">
        <% if(page < pages) { %>
            <a href="<%= link + linkDelimiter + (page+1) %>">Next</a>
        <% } %>
    </div>

<% } %>
```